# Como chamar uma variável dentro de outra função

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando chamar a variável nome dentro da funcão avancaQuadro. Mas não está funcionando.

```
var pergunta = document.querySelectorAll(".pergunta");
var indiceAtual = 0;

function iniciar(){
    pergunta[0].style.display = "block";
}

function avancaPergunta(){ //pula de pergunta em pergunta
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;    
    var mesNascimento = document.getElementById("mes-nascimento").value;
    var cor = document.getElementById("cor").value;
    pergunta[indiceAtual].style.display = "none";
    if (indiceAtual +1 >= pergunta.length){
        alert("você terminou o quiz");
        return;
    }

    pergunta[indiceAtual+1].style.display = "block";
    indiceAtual++; 

}

function avancaQuadro(){
    document.getElementById("resultado22").innerHTML = nome;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A função avancaQuadro não está recebendo nenhum parâmetro para repassar. Coloque o parâmetro nome dentro dos parenteses:

```
function avancaQuadro(nome){
    document.getElementById("resultado22").innerHTML = nome;

}
```

E quando for chamar a função, você informa o parâmetro para ser usado:

```
avancaQuadro('um texto');
```

A variável `nome` que você criou na função `avancaPergunta()` será acessada somente dentro do escopo desta função. Se você pretender usar esta mesma variável em outros lugares, ela precisa ser declarada fora do escopo.

Comment: Roberto, fiz essa alteração.. coloquei a variável nome fora da função, mas não está rolando... Não sei se o problema 
var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value; 

function avancaPergunta(){ //pula de pergunta em pergunta    
    pergunta[indiceAtual].style.display = "none";
    if (indiceAtual +1 >= pergunta.length){
        alert("você terminou o quiz");
        return;
    }

    pergunta[indiceAtual+1].style.display = "block";
    indiceAtual++; 

}

function avancaQuadro(){
    document.getElementById("resultado22").innerHTML = nome;    
}

Comment: Chame a variável sem o .value no final e dentro da função avancaQuadro, tente definir o innerHTML com nome.value; para ver se funciona então.